# How to duplicate a wordpress post to another wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, duplicates

How can i create and update post from one WordPress site to another WordPress site.

What i want is when i create a post on **site1** it will automatically create with same category into **site2**  and when i update a post in site1 it will auto update site2.

I've tried using feed but feed will only update some text but not videos inside post or other html content.

I also try to use IFTTT, but it only create post not update.

Any little help or suggestion appreciated.

I already know the impact of SEO in this.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, Either you can publish post via email or using plugins suggested in Wordpress official codex documentation.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_by_Email

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, i think it works the same way as ifttt does, it creates a post but not update when the original post updates.

Comment: Yes, correct. We have to write custom code for updating the posts remotely. But it's possible.